# Определение номера колонки Grid при FixedCols = 1

Tags: база-данных, delphi, компоненты

Есть компонент TbvDBGrid, при нажатии на определенном столбце привязанном у полю «SIGN» (второй столбец, у которого SelectedIndex = 1), у меня должно происходить определенное действие.

```
procedure TFRate.bvdbgrRateDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if bvdbgrRate.Columns[bvdbgrRate.SelectedIndex].FieldName = 'SIGN' then
  begin
    FMain.ibdsPair.Edit;
    if FMain.ibdsPair.FieldByName('SIGN').AsInteger = 0 then
      FMain.ibdsPair.FieldByName('SIGN').AsInteger := 1
    else
      FMain.ibdsPair.FieldByName('SIGN').AsInteger := 0;
    FMain.ibdsPair.Post;
    FMain.ibtrMain.CommitRetaining;
  End
```

Проблема появилась тогда, когда сделал 1 фиксированный столбец в *bvDBGrid* (*FixedCols := 1*).

Дело в том что при нажатии мышкой на этом фиксированном столбце (самом левом в таблице) - SelectedIndex равно не «0» (соответственно этот столбец привязан **НЕ** к полю "SIGN"), а «1».
Фокус мышки при этом всеравно приходится на вторую (слева) колонку, в результате не правильно определяется номер столбца.
В результате идет выполнение кода.

Как мне избежать подобной неприятности?

Comment: Сделать `SelectedIndex - 1` ?

Comment: обошелся методом "MouseCoord", **Спасибо**